# How could I run this process (v4l2rtspserver) in the background?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, v4l2

I am trying to run on Debian system (**Dietpi** on **Raspberry Pi**):

```
v4l2rtspserver -H 1080 -W 1920 -F 30 -P 8555 /dev/video0
```

But it keeps running in the command console despite adding **& disown**

I have also tried with **& jobs** but as if nothing, it keeps running in the command console and not in the background.

What I have noticed is that **v4l2rtspserver** runs several processes, I imagine that could be the problem there.

```
   [1]+  Running                 v4l2rtspserver -H 1080 -W 1920 -F 30 -P 8555 /dev/video0 &
dietpi@DietPi:~$ log level:500

[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/main.cpp:297
        Version: 0.3.3-8-gb007df2 live555 version:2022.04.26
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/src/V4l2RTSPServer.cpp:37
        Create V4L2 Source.../dev/video0
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2Device.cpp:133
        driver:bm2835 mmal capabilities:85200005 mandatory:4000001
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2Device.cpp:136
        /dev/video0 support capture
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2Device.cpp:138
        /dev/video0 support read/write
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2Device.cpp:139
        /dev/video0 support streaming
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2Device.cpp:225
        /dev/video0:H264 size:1920x1080 bufferSize:2088960
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2Device.cpp:246
        fps:1/30
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2Device.cpp:247
        nbBuffer:1
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2MmapDevice.cpp:49
        Device /dev/video0
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/v4l2wrapper/src/V4l2MmapDevice.cpp:73
        Device /dev/video0 nb buffer:10
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/src/V4l2RTSPServer.cpp:62
        Create Source .../dev/video0
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/src/V4L2DeviceSource.cpp:96
        begin thread
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/inc/BaseServerMediaSubsession.h:49
        format:video/H264
[NOTICE] /home/dietpi/v4l2rtspserver/inc/V4l2RTSPServer.h:80
```

I've only been using **Linux** for a short time and I couldn't identify the problem. What's going on? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to **user1686**'s solution now it runs in the background without problems, but I'm trying to get it to run the script when the system boots but I can't. I have added in **/etc/systemd/system/v4l2rtsp.service**:

```
[Unit]

Description=prueba

After=dev-video0.device

[Service]
Type=exec
User=dietpi
ExecStart=/home/dietpi/script_v4l2rtsp.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I have saved the file, and I have put this command, but the stream does not start:

```
sudo systemctl start v4l2rtsp
```

I have also tried to make it run on startup like this, but nothing either:

```
sudo systemctl enable v4l2rtsp
```

Although if I run the file independently, it works perfectly:

```
dietpi@DietPi:~$ sudo bash script_v4l2rtsp.sh
[1]+ Running v4l2rtspserver -H 1080 -W 1920 -F 30 -P 8555 /dev/video0 &> /dev/null &
dietpi@DietPi:~$
```

That could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* running in the background – you can see that you're immediately returning to the shell prompt (the `dietpi@DietPi:~$`). This is guaranteed to happen when using the `&` operator and there's no way for a program to bypass that.

However, `&` only makes the shell no longer wait for the process to finish running, but does not actually detach the program's *output* from the terminal it's running in. (Neither does `disown`, it just tells the shell to not kill the background job on logout.) So you can still interact with the shell in foreground, but the shell's output is interleaved with the background process output.

To discard output, redirect it using `>/dev/null 2>&1`:

```
$ v4l2rtspserver ..... >&/dev/null &
$ disown
```

But really you shouldn't be doing any of this in the first place – you should be configuring v4l2rtspserver as a *service*. Most Linux distributions come with some kind of service manager (such as systemd or Upstart) that starts and manages background tasks, and it shouldn't take more than a few lines to define a new service that you can control this way.

For example, Debian uses systemd, where a basic service (`/etc/systemd/system/v4l2rtsp.service`) would be defined like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Webcam RTSP server
After=dev-video0.device

[Service]
Type=exec
User=dietpi
ExecStart=v4l2rtspserver -H 1080 -W 1920 -F 30 -P 8555 /dev/video0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This would allow you to control the service using `systemctl start v4l2rtsp` or even make it automatically start on boot using `systemctl enable`.

Comment: Thank you very much mate. It has worked perfectly and is now running in the background. But I can't get it to run automatically when the system boots. Maybe I have something wrong. I also need to add a couple of commands, which is why I need it to be inside a shell. I have edited the question with all the information. Many thanks.

Comment: What does the script contain? Most of the time, the commands can be added to ExecStartPre or similar. Does the service log anything to the system log (journalctl -b) when the system boots, and what status (systemctl status) does it report?